# use iPhone as keyboard wedge with bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode5

I'm trying to create an application where I can send a string from an iPhone to an active textfield on my mac.  I'm coming from a Microsoft background and they call it focus.  The active textfield is not part of my application (3rd party).

I tested the concept by creating an iOS app to send a string to a mac via bluetooth. The mac (cocoa app) presents the string, in a label, in an NSWindow.

I want to create a keyboard wedge like a USB device to input the string in a textfield with   a Safari webpage open using the active text box.  I see there is a CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent in Apple's documentation.  My question is can I pass the entire string to a Keyboard event with out having to input each CGKeyCode possibilities, and coding each true/false for keyup and keydown?

I must be missing a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no universal "better way", since, unlike Microsoft, Apple knows something about security and is not going to let just any old process out of the blue start manipulating the text entered in some application's text box. However, there is a hole which you can ask the user to open: if the user has granted Accessibility permissions, then you can use the Accessibility API to "see" interface of the target application and to make changes like modifying the text in a text box. That is how applications like Nuance Dragon Dictate for Mac and Smile TextExpander work.